# org-mode: image file names in LaTeX export when using INCLUDE

Tags: org-mode, org-export

When using `INCLUDE` in an org-file:

```
#+INCLUDE: preamble/preamble.org
```

..and referring to an image in the included file..

```
* Preamble

Look at this amazing image:
[[./figure1.png]]
```

and then generating LaTeX for the top-level file, the resulting TeX is:

```
\part{Preamble}
\label{sec:orgheadline3}

Look at this amazing image:

\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{./figure1.png}
```

i.e., the path to the image is relative to the `preamble` directory, but the `.tex` file is one level up.

Is there a way to fix that (so that `includegraphics` refers to `preamble/figure1.png`)?